# Binding new ssl certificate to IIS7.5 website from command prompt (old ssl is going to expire soon)

Tags: asp.net, ssl

I have number of sites configured using https binding. But the current SSL certificate is going to expire in a week. I have installed renewd ssl certificate in the system(windows server 2008r2). Both the old and the new ssl certificates are with same name and I tried this command => appcmd set site /site.name:"mysitename" /+bindings.[protocol='https',bindingInformation='*:443:sub.mydomain.com']

but getting this error ERROR ( message:New binding object missing required attributes. Cannot add duplicate collection entry of type 'binding' with combined key attributes 'protocol,
bindingInformation' respectively set to 'https, *:443:sub.mydomain.com'
. )

Comment: basically do I need to remove existing ssl binding to add new ssl binding?

Comment: Search for `netsh http`.